# Creating a repeating line through looping by giving the x and y coordinates

Tags: vb.net, coordinates, paintevent

I am experimenting on the paint event of VB.Net, and for this experiment I would like to create a repeating horizontal or vertical (depending on the parameter that I inputted) line and loop through until it meets the corresponding end point x and y.

Something like this:

[image]

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is given the **x and y start point** and **x and y end point** the function should create either vertical or horizontal line that starts with the given start point until it reaches the given end point.

I can create curveline and straightline using the paintevent, but right now I don't have any idea on how to perform looping in the given x and y start point and end point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a For loop to iterate the x/y coordinates.  Here's an example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Enum Orientation
        Vertical
        Horizontal
    End Enum

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)

        Dim orient As Orientation = Orientation.Vertical
        Dim x As Integer = 100          'X Coord
        Dim y As Integer = 100          'Y Coord
        Dim count As Integer = 10       'Number of Lines to draw
        Dim spacing As Integer = 5      'Spacing between lines in pixels
        Dim length As Integer = 20      'Length of each line in pixels
        Dim thickness As Integer = 3    'Thickness of each line in pixels

        drawLines(x, y, orient, count, spacing, length, thickness, e.Graphics)
    End Sub

    Private Sub drawLines(x As Integer, y As Integer, orient As Orientation, count As Integer, spacing As Integer, length As Integer, thickness As Integer, g As Graphics)

        'Create the Pen in a using block so it will be disposed.  
        'The code uses a red pen, you can use whatever color you want
        Using p As New Pen(Brushes.Red, CSng(thickness))

            'Here we iterate either the x or y coordinate to draw each
            'small segment.
            For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                If orient = Orientation.Horizontal Then
                    g.DrawLine(p, x + ((thickness + spacing) * i), y, x + ((thickness + spacing) * i), y + length)
                Else
                    g.DrawLine(p, x, y + ((thickness + spacing) * i), x + length, y + ((thickness + spacing) * i))
                End If
            Next

        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is really really really great! I din't expect it to be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
For x = xstart to xend Step Spacing

Next
```

Where:

- xstart = your start point
- xend = your end point
- Spacing = distance between lines